# @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false) is not working in Spring 4.2.0 and upper version

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false) is not working with spring 4.2.0 and upper version of spring. But it is working with 4.0.4 and 4.0.1 .
I am using spring 4.2.8 and Jackson dependencies are used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If I send json request with invalid fields then it is accepting as a valid request. But it should give the bad request as response.
For example: If I have class

```
public class Student{ 
    private String id; 
    private String name; 
}
```

If send valid corresponding json request it should be like

```
{ 
   "id": "123", 
   "name": "test" 
}
```

But even if I send json request with invalid fields like below it is still accepting.

```
{ 
    "id": "123", 
    "name": "test", 
    "anyinvalidkey": "test" 
}
```

But it should give the bad request as response

Answer (score 6):

An annotation based solution to the based on the answer from Aarya can done in the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter converter;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        configureJacksonToFailOnUnknownProperties();
    }

    private void configureJacksonToFailOnUnknownProperties() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter = converter.getMessageConverters().stream()
                .filter(mc -> mc.getClass().equals(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class))
                .map(mc -> (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)mc)
                .findFirst()
                .get();

        httpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there one annotation to just toggle this feature instead of copy paste this configuration?

Comment: `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` or you can use it globally in you property file `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true`

Answer (score 3):

Easy annotation driven solution. In a @Configuration:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `HttpMessageConverter` provided by the earlier versions of spring were using `ObjectMapper` default configuration. But the newer versions of spring use `Jackson2ObjectMapperBulider` which has `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` property set to false by default. (Reference [link](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)). You can solve this issue by adding the following in your applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />

<mvc:annotation-driven
    content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <value>
            json=application/json
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: How do you do this with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

@Aarya's answer did not work for me right out of box, but gave me a great hint to look around. So this is what works for me. Given that my Spring is 4.3.12.RELEASE and jackson is 2.9.2

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```