# How to restrict JSON payload from containing additional fields with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a basic User DTO class...

```
public class User {

  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  private String firstName;

  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  private String lastName;
}
```

...and a basic request handler in a @RestController class:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public UserMessage createUser(@RequestBody User user){
   return userService.createUser(user);
}
```

How can I restrict incoming JSON payloads to contain at most only the required keys? 
i.e. accept this payload:

```
{
  "firstName":"foo",
  "lastName":"bar"
}
```

And throw a custom exception on this:

```
{
  "firstName":"foo",
  "lastName":"bar",
  "type":"admin",
  "asdf":"asdf"
}
```

I read about custom Converters, ArgumentResolvers, and I believe I could simply put an additional Map parameter in the handler and validate before service call, however I'd like to know the "best" way of handling this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, this thread helped
[@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false) is not working in Spring 4.2.0 and upper version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128623/jsonignorepropertiesignoreunknown-false-is-not-working-in-spring-4-2-0-and-up)

mle, your answer wasn't right, since I was using the latest version of Spring Framework and the ObjectMapper's `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` is turned off by default. Additionally I was needed to set `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)` in my User DTO class (as the actual class' superclass had this set to true).

Tested it, runs like a charm, while custom errors can be handled in a `@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)` annotated handler.

Comment: Well if you are using super classes or more generally code you do not put in your question, it is hard for us to get the actual issue.

Comment: I might agree, but still the actual code I'm working on is not relevant to the issue in general, and any user might want to configure both the ObjectMapper and the DTO with relevant annotations and configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `User` bean in your example it also **already not possible**, that potential other JSON fields than `firstName` and `lastName` could be mapped, simply because there are no fields in `User` which could hold the relevant data.

Should the `User` bean in your question be not complete, e.g. for simplicity reasons, and contain more fields, also then should everything be fine, as long as you did not configure your your `ObjectMapper` with [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features) **=> false** or you use the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on your bean.

To sum it up: Jackson's default behavior is `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES (default: true)`

For further information you can also consult the [respective Deserialization docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It didn't solve the issue, but pushed me to search further. I actually found a solution, described in an answer to the question. You weren't wrong about your solution though, but it only works on older versions of Spring.

Comment: Oh it works also for Spring Boot 2.1.3. Anyway... if my answer did not solve your problem but was nevertheless helpful, please consider an upvote. :-)